# Adding components by constructor

Tags: java, swing

I have problem with adding Label by constructor, when I make it by method it's no problem

```
private void addLabel() {
    System.out.println("asd");
    JLabel label = new JLabel("asd");
    label.setBounds(10, 40, 100, 25);
    add(label);
    repaint();
    validate();
    System.out.println("asd2");
}
```

But when i try to do this same by new class and constructor i doesn't work...

Main frame:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {

JButton button = new JButton("new");
AddButton button2 = new AddButton();

public Frame() {
    setLayout(null);
    setSize(400, 500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    button.setBounds(40, 10, 50, 25);
    add(button);


    button2.setBounds(40, 40, 100, 25);
    add(button);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Frame ap = new Frame();
    ap.setVisible(true);
}
```

AddButton class:

```
public class AddButton extends JPanel {
JLabel label = new JLabel("asd");

public AddButton() {
    label.setBounds(10, 40, 100, 25);
    add(label);
    repaint();
    validate();

  }

}
```

---

Ok i got it, I tried to add "button" two times istead button and button2 :D

Comment: `label.setBounds(10, 40, 100, 25);`  Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: Add declaration of JLabel to conctructor too.

Comment: Please give more code for context.  And what does "doesn't work" mean?  Please be specific.  Do you get an exception? If so, post the stack trace.   Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

Your [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) doesn't make sense, that's not how you should use constructors - constructors are used to create an *instance* of a class.

When you write

```
AddButton button2 = new AddButton();
```

then `button2` is of type `AddButton`, and [`add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add(java.awt.Component)) doesn't accept this type of object.

Comment: So, how to change it ?

Comment: @GumovvySteven Don't use constructor, also note that you already `add`ed the label in your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can Edit like this

```
public class AddButton extends JPanel {
JLabel label; 

public AddButton() {
label=new JLabel("asd");
label.setBounds(10, 40, 100, 25);
add(label);
repaint();
validate();

}

}
```